# Webmin Filesystem backup | Restoration complete without errors, but doesn't works

Tags: unix, backup, restore, dump, webmin

I am using the "**Filesystem Backup**" from **Webmin**, but this recovering system doesn't works on my server.

Here my config :

- Debian **10** (Buster)
- Webmin version **1.970**

And here, what i've done :

1. [Backup creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZqgK.png)
2. Manual modification of a file to create a difference between my backup version and the post-backup version.
3. [Restoring the backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OakoK.png) : the action log tells me that the restoration is complete.

But when I go to see my files, nothing has moved.

I don't know where to go to see if there is any error, I don't know where it could come from ... any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "`Only show files in backup`" is set to "**No**"

[Src](https://dannyda.com/2020/07/21/how-to-fix-webmin-restore-file-system-failed-due-to-browser-crash-timeout/)